# Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm fairly new at Xcode, and coding in general, so please bear with me here lol. I am working on my first app for a science fair project which is tab-based with two main pages. One page contains several switches; whichever switch is on determines what sound or animation the large button on the other page plays.

After looking at several tutorials and creating my storyboard, I began coding the part which would connect the action to the button to the switch. I continue to receive the following error on the line where I have the `pushButton` function: `Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction`

I have checked my parenthesis and brackets and I don't believe there is an error, but as I am a beginner, I could be missing something. My code is pasted below, and any help is appreciated. The empty switch functions will be like the first one, once I get this issue figured out. :)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var CatSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:    "CatSound", ofType: "mp3")!)

    //Mark: Properties
    @IBOutlet var pushButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func meowSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        while (sender.isOn == true) {
            @IBAction func pushButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
                let CatSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:  "CatSound", ofType: "mp3")!)
                do {
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: CatSound)
                    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                } catch {
                    print("Problem in getting File")
                }
                audioPlayer.play()
            }
        }

    }

    @IBAction func barkSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    }

    @IBAction func carSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    }

    @IBAction func trainSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    }

    @IBAction func helloSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    }

    @IBAction func applauseSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with:

```
@IBAction func meowSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    while (sender.isOn == true) {
        @IBAction func pushButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

You can not declare an function inside of another function like that.

You should create a separate function `func playMeowSound(){...}` that has the code inside of `pushButton(_ sender: UIButton)`, and then do:

```
@IBAction func meowSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    while (sender.isOn == true) {
        playMeowSound()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These 2 functions can't be inside each others

```
 @IBAction func meowSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
while (sender.isOn == true) {
    @IBAction func pushButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let CatSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:  "CatSound", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: CatSound)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("Problem in getting File")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}

}
```

split like this

```
  @IBAction func pushButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let CatSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:  "CatSound", ofType: "mp3")!)
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: CatSound)
        /// set repeats here if you want
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    } catch {
        print("Problem in getting File")
    }
    audioPlayer.play()
```

////

```
 @IBAction func meowSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {

       if(sender.isOn) {      
          self.pushButton(self.pushBtn)    
       }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that this is what you want:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var CatSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:    "CatSound", ofType: "mp3")!)

    //Mark: Properties

    @IBAction func pushButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if UserDefaults.standard.playMeowSound {
            playMeow()
        } // else if UserDefaults.standard.playBarkSound { etc.
    }

    func playMeow() {
        let CatSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:  "CatSound", ofType: "mp3")!)
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: CatSound)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("Problem in getting File")
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func meowSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        UserDefaults.standard.playMeowSound = sender.isOn
        if sender.isOn == true {
            // turn off all the other switches, e.g.:
            // barkSwitch.isOn = false
            // UserDefaults.standard.playBarkSound = false
        }
    }
}

extension UserDefaults {
    private static let playMeowSoundKey = "org.stackoverflow.playMeowSoundKey"

    var playMeowSound: Bool {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: UserDefaults.playMeowSoundKey)
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaults.playMeowSoundKey)
        }
    }
}
```

`pushButton` is an `@IBAction` linked to the push button. When pressed, this handler tests which switch is set on, and plays the sound that you need. You want `@IBOutlet`s for the switches, so that you can test their state to find out which one is on.

Comment: The code is no longer showing an error with this part, but I'm not sure how to connect the switches to those in my Interface builder because they are in the 2nd view controller. Is there any way to do this? Is making that connection even necessary?

Comment: @AbbyCornell well, you need to have some access to those switches in order to determine which sound to play.. but if switches are in different viewController than the button that plays sound, it's gonna be a bit tough. You have to create `@IBOutlets` for switches in their respective controller, and there put the logic of switching between them. Then you have to somehow pass that information to the controller with button, when the user goes to that controller. Since I dont have access to the rest of your code, it's hard to suggest something.

Comment: @AbbyCornell but one way that would definitely work is storing the current state of the switches in UserDefaults (basically storing it to the permanent storage) everytime the switches change, and then in pressing the button you can read the current state from there.. that way you can use UserDefaults to "pass" that info between those controllers

Comment: @AbbyCornell I have updated my answer to provide a starting point for you

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you put a function inside another function the inner one belongs to the outer function, not instances of the class.

The way you have your code setup `pushButton` belongs to the `meowSwitch`method  not the `FirstViewController` class, as such you are not allowed to use the `@IBAction` keyword.

Based on the way you have described your project you should look at using a different interface. Given that you want the user to select a "sound or animation" to play when a button is pressed a `UIPickerView` with all the possibilities may work better for you.

Using switches means that the user could turn them all on at once, what would happen when the user presses the button then?

Given that you want to split things up over two view controllers, each in their own tab I would have the first tab take care of the picker and the second tab have the button that triggers the selected item.

In the first view controller you would use `func pickerView(_ : ,didSelectRow:  , inComponent: )` to store the user's selection in a user default.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if let chosen = self.pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow: row, forComponent: component) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(chosen, forKey: "selected")
    }
}
```

*Note that there is a bit more setup needed to get a `UIPickerView` working but there are plenty of tutorials around that explain it.*

Then the second view controller would read the default when the button was pressed, responding accordingly.

If all the options are audio files and their names match what you display in the picker view you could just use the string stored in the user default to play the right audio.

```
@IBAction func pushButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let selected = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selected") else { return }
    let sound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource:  selected, ofType: "mp3")!)
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    } catch {
        print("Problem in getting File")
    }
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```